# Calculate the order of deletes SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have a huge database that has lots and lots of poorly documented constraints.
I need to write some SQL to empty the data out of a subset of these tables, and I am not sure how to determine the order for the deletes. Obviously I need to delete the FK tables before the corresponding PK table, but as I say the relationships are tangled, and poorly documented.

Is there a tool available that will let me determine a correct order for my delete statements?

(I looked at Red Gate tools, and was absolutely amazed to find out they do not support SQL Server 2008R2 which is what I am using.)

Comment: Hi Fred. I'm the product manager for SQL Compare. We support SQL Server 2008 R2. If you had issues with this in the past, it could be that you came across a bug that has since been resolved. Would you be able to try this again and if you have issues, please email me directly at David dot Atkinson at red-gate dot com.

Comment: David, sorry if I dissed your product, but I have an email from one of your sales guys saying what I said above (he said you were bringing out a version in a few months that would support it.) I downloaded the trial version also, and could not open my database with a message saying something like "Version not supported." Do you have a link to a trial version of a tool that would do what I ask above?

Comment: There may not be a single "order" in which to perform the deletes. If there are any circular references (either a self reference, or a larger cycle), you may have to break the cycle first.

Comment: @Fred - the project manager is adamant that it should work as 2008 R2 is what is used internally. If you're getting an error, please let us know the version number of the tool so we can investigate. If you're interested in using the latest bleeding edge build, this is available from here: http://www.red-gate.com/MessageBoard/viewtopic.php?t=14113

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you could build a procedure to get the order. Here is an idea:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE get_delete_order
    @tablename varchar(MAX)
as

BEGIN
    -- Get directed related tables
    SELECT base.name base_name
         , related.name rel_name
      into #RELATED_TABLES
      FROM sys.sysobjects base 
      left join sys.sysforeignkeys on fkeyid = base.id
      left join sys.sysobjects related on related.id = rkeyid
                                      and related.id <> base.id
                                      and related.xtype = 'U'
    WHERE base.xtype = 'U'
      and base.name = @tablename

    -- Get indirected related tables using recursive call
    CREATE #ALL_RELATED_TABLES (rel_name varchar(max), del_order int)
    INSERT INTO #ALL_RELATED_TABLES (rel_name, del_order)
        SELECT rel_name
             , -1
          FROM #RELATED_TABLES

    DECLARE @relate_table
    DECLARE IND_REL CURSOR FOR
        SELECT rel_Name
          FROM #RELATED_TABLES
    open IND_REL
    fetch next from IND_REL into @relate_table

    -- TODO: IMPORTANT!!! Avoid infinite loop here
    while (@@FETCH_STATUS = 0)
    begin
        INSERT INTO #ALL_RELATED_TABLES (rel_name, del_order)
            exec get_delete_order(@relate_table)
        fetch next from IND_REL into @relate_table
    end
    close IND_REL
    deallocate IND_REL

    -- Return resultset
      SELECT rel_name
           , del_order + 1
        FROM #ALL_RELATED_TABLES
    ORDER BY del_order DESC
END
```

It is untested, just an idea.
Real procedure would be more complicated :)

Comment: This helped, I used it to get data which I then manipulated by hand in Excel. For future readers you might also check out the script at this URL: http://bytestopshere.wordpress.com/2008/11/01/sql-server-script-to-find-foreign-key-dependencies/  Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Just pasting the script from Fred Thomas' blog here for future reference. It worked well for me.

```
select cast(f.name  as varchar(255)) as foreign_key_name
    , r.keycnt
    , cast(c.name as  varchar(255)) as foreign_table
    , cast(fc.name as varchar(255)) as  foreign_column_1
    , cast(fc2.name as varchar(255)) as foreign_column_2
    ,  cast(p.name as varchar(255)) as primary_table
    , cast(rc.name as varchar(255))  as primary_column_1
    , cast(rc2.name as varchar(255)) as  primary_column_2
from sysobjects f
inner join sysobjects c on  f.parent_obj = c.id
inner join sysreferences r on f.id =  r.constid
inner join sysobjects p on r.rkeyid = p.id
inner  join syscolumns rc on r.rkeyid = rc.id and r.rkey1 = rc.colid
inner  join syscolumns fc on r.fkeyid = fc.id and r.fkey1 = fc.colid
left join  syscolumns rc2 on r.rkeyid = rc2.id and r.rkey2 = rc.colid
left join  syscolumns fc2 on r.fkeyid = fc2.id and r.fkey2 = fc.colid
where f.type =  'F'
ORDER BY cast(p.name as varchar(255))
```